# How to delete duplicate rows in sybase, when you have no unique key?

Tags: sql, sybase, duplicates, sqlanywhere

Yes, you can find similar questions numerous times, but:
the most elegant solutions posted here, work for SQL Server, but not for Sybase (in my case Sybase Anywhere 11). I have even found some Sybase-related questions marked as duplicates for SQL Server questions, which doesn't help.

One example for solutions I liked, but didn't work, is the `WITH ... DELETE ...` construct.

I have found working solutions using cursors or while-loops, but I hope it is possible without loops.

I hope for a nice, simple and fast query, just deleting all but one exact duplicate.

Here a little framework for testing:

```
IF OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb..#TestTable' ) IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #TestTable;

CREATE TABLE #TestTable (Column1 varchar(1), Column2 int);

INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A', 1);
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A', 1); -- duplicate
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A', 1); -- duplicate
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A', 2);
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('B', 1);
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('B', 2);
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('B', 2); -- duplicate
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('C', 1);
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('C', 2);

SELECT * FROM #TestTable ORDER BY Column1,Column2;

DELETE <your solution here>

SELECT * FROM #TestTable ORDER BY Column1,Column2;
```

Comment: Hmmm. 6200 views, but no one found any of my answers useful?

Comment: It only took 10 years and 26000 views to get upvoted :)

Comment: ...but I really don't understand the votes to the answers. Don't people like it when someone answers their own questions? @zx8754

Comment: I don't know sql deep enough to know which answer is the right one, we can only assume/hope people who voted do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, now that I know the `ROWID()` function, solutions for tables with primary key (PK) can be easily adopted. This one first selects all rows to keep and then deletes the remaining ones:

```
DELETE FROM #TestTable
FROM #TestTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(ROWID(#TestTable)) rowid
  FROM #TestTable
  GROUP BY Column1, Column2
) AS KeepRows ON ROWID(#TestTable) = KeepRows.rowid
WHERE KeepRows.rowid IS NULL;
```

...or how about this shorter variant? I like!

```
DELETE FROM #TestTable
WHERE ROWID(#TestTable) NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(ROWID(#TestTable))
  FROM #TestTable
  GROUP BY Column1, Column2
);
```

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949/1855801), which inspired me most, is a comment that `NOT IN` might be slower. But that's for SQL server, and sometimes elegance is more important :) - I also think it all depends on good indexes.

Anyway, usually it is bad design, to have tables without a PK. You should at least add an "autoinc" ID, and if you do, you can use that ID instead of the `ROWID()` function, which is a non-standard extension by Sybase (some others have it, too).

Answer (score 7):

If all fields are identical, you can just do this:

```
select distinct * 
into #temp_table
from table_with_duplicates 

delete table_with_duplicates 

insert into table_with_duplicates select * from #temp_table
```

If all fields are not identical, for example, if you have an id that is different, then you'll need to list all the fields in the select statement, and hard code a value in the id to make it identical, if that is a field you don't care about.
For example:

```
insert #temp_table field1, field2, id select (field1, field2, 999)
from table_with_duplicates
```

Comment: What if I have millions of records and just a few duplicates? It is a straightforward and easy to remember solution, if you once and manually need to get rid of duplicates. But it could be much slower, needs a temporary table, and is not exactly what was asked for. In addition, the title already says there is no ID (primary key) - if you have an ID, you could anyway use many other solutions which require a primary key.

Comment: A `select` and some `;` are missing :)

Answer (score 2):

This works well and fast:

```
DELETE FROM #TestTable
WHERE ROWID(#TestTable) IN (
  SELECT rowid FROM (
    SELECT ROWID(#TestTable) rowid, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1,Column2 ORDER BY Column1,Column2) rownum
    FROM #TestTable
  ) sub
  WHERE rownum > 1
);
```

If you don't know `OVER(PARTITION BY ...)`, just execute the inner `SELECT` statement to see what it does.

Comment: The ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY XX) function is only valid for Adaptive Server Enterprise.

Comment: It worked with Sybase Anywhere 11

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
create clustered index i1 on table table_name(column_name) with ignore_dup_row
```

```
create table #test(id int,name char(9))
insert into #test values(1,"A")
insert into #test values(1,"A")
create clustered index i1 on #test(id) with ignore_dup_row
select * from #test
```

Comment: Thanks, it's quite interesting to learn about Sybase options ignore_dup_row and allow_dup_row. But it doesn't seem to work with my Sybase version: there is no error when creating the index, but the option seems to be ignored and the select returns both rows.

Comment: Looks like it is only valid for Adaptive Server Enterprise (Sybase ASE) - I just wonder why it doesn't give any error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another interesting one I found and adopted:

```
DELETE FROM #TestTable dupes
FROM #TestTable dupes, #TestTable fullTable
WHERE dupes.Column1 = fullTable.Column1
  AND dupes.Column2 = fullTable.Column2
  AND ROWID(dupes) > ROWID(fullTable);
```

or, if you like explicit joins more (I do):

```
DELETE FROM #TestTable dupes
FROM #TestTable dupes
INNER JOIN #TestTable fullTable
  ON dupes.Column1 = fullTable.Column1
  AND dupes.Column2 = fullTable.Column2
  AND ROWID(dupes) > ROWID(fullTable);
```

or the short form (a "natural" join incorporates identical column names automatically):

```
DELETE FROM #TestTable dupes
FROM #TestTable dupes
NATURAL JOIN #TestTable fullTable
  ON ROWID(dupes) > ROWID(fullTable);
```

...if someone finds a solution not requiring `ROWID()`, I would be interested to see them.

Comment: Yes, joining the row IDs with "greater than" is quite cool and very valid to surprise a colleague ;-) - but when you think about what this really does... I feel like a sadistic db torturer... or could the optimizer be _that_ smart and just laugh at me?